# Python Crypted error "UnicodeEncodeError"

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I Tried to creat a code for simulate a register.

The user choose for exemple to "create a account" and stock the usename and password in a txt named username.txt

This part work but now I trie to crypted the password but I obtened:

"File "C:\Program\Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x95' in position 2: character maps to "undefined".

But if I use my programm to crypted lonnely that work

my code:

```
# coding: utf-8

import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import os
import time
import platform
import shutil
import sys
import _socket
import socket
from Cryptage import *

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cle= open("cle.txt","r", encoding="utf-8")
cle=cle.read()
colorama.init(autoreset = True)
Boucle = 1
Pseudo = ""
encoded_string = ''

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def Clean():
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        os.system("cls")
    elif platform.system() == "Linux":
        os.system("clear")

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def Acceuil():

    Clean()
    print(Fore.BLUE+"<===ACCEUIL===>")
    print(Fore.BLUE+"---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print(Fore.BLUE+"1. Se connecter")
    print(Fore.BLUE+"2. S'inscrire")
    print(Fore.BLUE+"3. Quitter")
    print(Fore.BLUE+"---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    choix = input()

    if choix =='1':
        Connexion()
    
    elif choix =='2':
        Register()
    
    elif choix =='3':
        Clean()
        print("Fin du programme...")
        time.sleep(2.4)
        sys.exit()

    else:
        Clean()
        print(Fore.RED + "invalide")
        colorama.init(autoreset = True)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def Register():

    Clean()

    print(Fore.BLUE+"<===INSCRIPTION===>")
    print(Fore.BLUE+"---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    Pseudo, MDP = input(Fore.BLUE+"Pseudo, MDP: ").split()


    TxtUser = "{Pseudo2}.txt".format(Pseudo2=Pseudo)
    CheminBase = "C:\\Users\\yuris\\Desktop\\Python\\GestionDeCompte\\{TxtUser2}".format(TxtUser2=TxtUser)
    CheminArriver = "C:\\Users\\yuris\\Desktop\\Python\\GestionDeCompte\\Users\\{TxtUser2}".format(TxtUser2=TxtUser)

    MDPcrypted = encode(cle, MDP)

if os.path.exists(CheminArriver):

    Clean()
    print(Fore.RED+"Le Pseudo",Fore.RED+Pseudo,Fore.RED+"Existe deja")
    input()

 
else:

    NewUser = open(TxtUser,"x")
    NewUser.close()

    NewUser = open(TxtUser,"a")
    NewUser.write("Pseudo: ")
    NewUser.write(Pseudo)
    NewUser.write("! ")

    NewUser.write("MDP: ")
    NewUser.write( MDPcrypted)
    NewUser.write("!")
    NewUser.close()

    shutil.move(CheminBase,CheminArriver)
    print(Fore.BLUE+"Déplacement vers connexion...")
    time.sleep(2.4)
    Connexion()

        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def Connexion():

    Clean()
    print(Fore.BLUE+"<===CONNEXION===>")
    print(Fore.BLUE+"---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    Pseudo, MDP = input(Fore.BLUE+"Pseudo, MDP: ").split()
    print(Fore.BLUE+"---------------------------------------------------------------------")

    TxtUser = "{Pseudo2}.txt".format(Pseudo2=Pseudo)
    CheminArriver = "C:\\Users\\yuris\\Desktop\\Python\\GestionDeCompte\\Users\\{TxtUser2}".format(TxtUser2=TxtUser)

    if os.path.exists(CheminArriver) :

        MDPregister = "{MDP2}!".format(MDP2=MDP)
        UserConnect = open(CheminArriver,"r")
    
        for ligne in  UserConnect:
            if MDPregister in ligne:
                MenuPrincipal()
            else:
                print(Fore.RED+"Le Pseudo ou le MDP est invalide")
                input()
 
    else:
        print(Fore.RED+"Le Pseudo ou le MDP est invalide")
        input()

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def MenuPrincipal():
    while Boucle != 0:

        Clean()
   
        print(Fore.GREEN+"Bienvenue",Fore.GREEN+Pseudo)
        input()
 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

while Boucle != 0:

    Acceuil()
    print("")
```

And this is my programm for crypted the password:

```
# coding: utf-8
# vigenere cipher

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cle= open("cle.txt","r", encoding="utf-8")
cle=cle.read()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
def encode(cle, string):
    encoded_chars = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        key_c =cle[i % len(cle)]
        encoded_c = chr(ord(string[i]) + ord(key_c) % 256)
        encoded_chars.append(encoded_c)
    encoded_string = ''.join(encoded_chars)
    return encoded_string

def decode(cle, string):
    encoded_chars = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        key_c = cle[i % len(cle)]
        encoded_c = chr((ord(string[i]) - ord(key_c) + 256) % 256)
        encoded_chars.append(encoded_c)
    encoded_string = ''.join(encoded_chars)
    return encoded_string
```

(Re:Programme Modified)

Answer (score 0):

Your first line should read `# coding: utf-8` or `coding=utf-8` (take out the `en`), or specify when you read in `cle` that `cle = open("cle.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")`. You are using a different codec than utf-8.

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: I see the modifications to your question; it is difficult for me to reproduce the error you are getting (it works for me) since you seem to have some local modules imported and used in your code. Can you create a reproducible example of the first code block you posted?

Comment: First line specifies the encoding of the *source file* and has nothing to do with reading other files.  The default encoding for a Python 3 source file is UTF-8 anyway, so the line is not needed. `encoding` is also valid for that line. See [encoding- declarations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations).